# What's the best way to integrate Facebook SDK in cross platform libGDX project?

Tags: libgdx

Till now I haven't found clarity on how to integrate 3rd party services in a libGDX project. 
My project targets Android and iOS both the platforms.

Can someone tell me the best ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook or write your own platform specific code https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: Hey @tomgrill-games gdx-facebook is okay. I am more interested in platform specific code since it looks like that is the only solution where I can work independently with any 3rd party sdk. The issue for me now is I don't see a clear implementation for iOS

Comment: The iOS implementation requires you to write so called bindings which wrap java code around iOS code. https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm-robopods are some libraries which have already been binded.